# Running Google Dataflow locally for Image Recognition

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, image-recognition, google-cloud-ml

I am currently following this tutorial for transfer learning using tensorflow and Google Cloud Platform.
https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/12/how-to-train-and-classify-images-using-google-cloud-machine-learning-and-cloud-dataflow

It works perfectly on the cloud with my own data when I use their sample code

```
# Preprocess the eval set.
python trainer/preprocess.py \
  --input_dict "$DICT_FILE" \
  --input_path "gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/eval_set.csv" \
  --output_path "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval" \
  --cloud
```

I get all the preprocessing, training and deployment done.

However, I would like to be able to run it locally so that I can make changes in the code and debug it more effieciently:
In the code it states that

```
To run this pipeline locally run the above command without --cloud.
```

So it would read:

```
# Preprocess the eval set.
python trainer/preprocess.py \
  --input_dict "$DICT_FILE" \
  --input_path "gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/eval_set.csv" \
  --output_path "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval"
```

I tried to run this code with input_dict, input_path and output_path set to a cloud storage path, as well as being a path to a file on my local machine.
However I get the error:

tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/google_auth_provider.cc:151] All attempts to get a Google authentication bearer token failed, returning an empty token. Retrieving token from files failed with "Unavailable: libcurl failed with error code 23: Failed writing body (91 != 196)". Retrieving token from GCE failed with "Unavailable: Unexpected response code 0".

So it seems to be an authentication issue:
The thing is that I do not have authentication problems when copying files from google cloud storage manually.

I already tried:

```
 $ gcloud auth application-default login
```

but it doesn't change anything.

Does anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: What version of TensorFlow are you using? python -c 'import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__version__)'

Comment: I am using version 0.11.0

Comment: There are known issues of how different versions of libcurl may cause problems here. They were addressed in TensorFlow 1.0, but currently the code you are using does not yet work with TF 1.0. We are updating the "flowers" sample code now and will let you know when it is ready, assuming you're willing to use TF 1.0 (which is the only officially supported version for CloudML).